# Создание сложного меню с помощью Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Текущее состояние [тут](http://osiyo-nur.uz/goodgross). Изменил  эффект при наведении на клик-эффект, однако работает очень паршиво. Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на любой элемент открывалось меню и при нажатии на другой элемент меню закрывался предыдущий нажатый элемент меню?

```js
$('.category li').click(function(event) {
  $(this).children('.r_div').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.category li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.r_div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    Menu #1
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #2
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #3
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #4
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #5
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.category li').click(function(event) {
  $('.category li').children('.r_div').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).children('.r_div').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.category li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.r_div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    Menu #1
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #2
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #3
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #4
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #5
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('.category li').click(function(event) {
  $('.r_div').hide(); // скрыть все с классом "r_div"
  $('.r_div', this).show(); // показать элемент с классом "r_div" относящийся к ДАННОМУ узлу (this)
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.category li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.r_div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    Menu #1
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #2
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #3
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #4
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #5
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете посмотреть jQueryUI [меню](https://jqueryui.com/menu/)

P.S. Может ещё что-то полезное найдете для себя, кроме меню